# How do I launch this web app

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, javabeans

I went through a tutorial how to create and deploy a web application that contains java beans. I then created the war file and deployed it to my Apache Tomcat server. Everything works fine up till point. Now all I want to do is just open one of the pages.

I thought that by entering this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/AGen/menu.xhtml
```

I would bring up a web page. But all I get is an http status 404. I checked the war file and the menu.xhtml is there. So I must be doing something wrong. Apache Tomcat is running and I can open up the admin console and see that my app is deployed.

Sorry, but I'm relatively new to this.

Here is a screen shot of what my Eclipse project looks like. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put your xhtml pages in `WEB-INF` folder. So you will not be able to access them from browser.

You need to put them in `WebContent` folder directly, not in WEB-INF.

Just put them in WebContent and you are done.

[FYI](http://www.coderanch.com/t/530570/Servlets/java/Accessing-files-WEB-INF)

Comment: Where should they be?

Comment: It works! Thanks a million, especially for the link.